# Phase Difference

Tags: power, current, ac, components, phasor

$$i_1 = sin(wt +45^0)  $$ $$ i_2 = -sin(wt +60^0)$$

Question : what is the phase difference dows  i1 lead  i2

My method

1 ) Eliminate minus sign that is i2 = sin(wt + 60 + 180 ) = sin(wt + 240 )

My answer is that i1 leads i2 by  45 - 240 = -195

but correct answer is i1 leads i2 by +165 deg

Comment: Try a couple of trig identities. Either of these should help.

Comment: $$\sin \left( -x \right)\; =\; -\sin \left( x \right)$$  $$\sin \left( x+\pi  \right)\; =\; -\sin \left( x \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

It is the same answer, -195 degrees = 165 degrees on the circle.

To convert negative degrees to positive, add 360.

Comment: adding - 180 to eliminate the minus sign in i2 yields , 165 phase difference . Then I tried both of these methods ( adding -180 or adding +180 ) to other problems and answers were the same (not 180 ) Why the answers are same in these Q