# Phase difference between two waves from wave equation

Tags: phase-shift, phasor

I need to calculate phase angle between

$$i_1 = -4\sin(377t + 55) \hspace{0.2cm}\quad \mathrm{and}\quad \hspace{0.2cm} i_2 = 5\cos(377t - 65)$$

I need to determine which one is leading too.

**My progress so far:**

$$\begin{align}i_1 &= -4 \sin(377t + 55)\\ &= 4\cos(377t + 55 + 90)\\ &= 4\cos(377t + 145)\\[1em]
i_2 &= 5\cos(377t - 65)\end{align}$$

So, we get phase difference = 145 - (-65) = 210, \$i_1\$ leads \$i_2\$ by 210.

But, $$\begin{align}i_2 &= 5\cos(377t - 65)\\ &= 5\cos(377t - 65 + 360)\\ &= 5\cos(377t + 295)\end{align}$$

Now, we get phase difference = 295 - 145 = 150, \$i_2\$ leads \$i_1\$ by 150.

Are both of these correct ?

Comment: I recommend collaborating with fellow students and see if they arrived at the same answer.

Comment: Can something lead or lag by more than 180 degrees? How do you define lead and lag?

Comment: I've got this problem in "Fundamentals of electric circuits" book written by Alexander & Sadiku . That gives 210 as answer. Please check this link for how I define lead or lag : https://imgur.com/a/UEXAy

Comment: @Utshaw That page doesn't define the meaning. Let me ask you this... Tell me, what is the difference between \$4\cdot \operatorname{cos}\left(377t+210^\circ\right)\$ and \$4\cdot \operatorname{cos}\left(377t-150^\circ\right)\$? I mean, if you plotted those two on the same chart from \$t=-\infty\$ to \$t=+\infty\$ would you be able to tell the difference?

Comment: I think , 4⋅cos(377t+210∘) will lead the other as it reaches it's maximum point earlier that the other (when I consider the two "nearest" peak points.  ).

Comment: To put it yet another way, what happens if you add +360 to -150? (360 being 1 full cycle)

Comment: when I add 360 to -150 it will give me 210. cos(t - 150) = cos(t - 150 + 360)  . But after I plotting I found that cos(t - 150) is not as same as cos(t + 210). I think, I am wrong with adding 360 with the angle.  I guess, I am missing some concept here. Please clarify.

Comment: Check out [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/96401/147249) question as well

Comment: What value do you get for cos -150 and what value do you get for cos 210?

Comment: @Utshaw They plot EXACTLY the same. There is no difference. None at all. You must be plotting in radians and incorrectly adding degrees, or something. Try using \$\operatorname{cos}\left(377 t+\frac{7}{6}\pi\right)\$ and \$\operatorname{cos}\left(377 t-\frac{5}{6}\pi\right)\$.

Comment: So, can I conclude that i1 leads i2 by x means i2 lags i1 by x or i2 leads i1 by (360 - x) ?

Comment: Side note (and this is rather my opinion): Matthew Sadiku writes _**really really really bad**_ textbooks. That being said, and I know the professor assigns certain textbooks for the course so that's out of your control, try to use some outside material when you want to try to learn something. Fundamentals of Circuits by Sadiku is okay at best... Digressing. Sorry... but why would you add 360 degrees?

Comment: @KingDuken , I prefer to get both the phase in positive form . So, I added 360 degree . May be I am wrong. What will be the correct approach to solve this problem without plotting ?